# Render a line or Dot using OpenGL on Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, opengl, webforms

How to render a line or a simple Dot on Asp.net (C# Web Forms without JavaScript) using OpenGL/WebGL?

Comment: You want WebGL not openGL.

Comment: @Rodrigo ... Ok help me to get started with WebGL .. I'll appreciate ..

Comment: My apologies I can only point you to documentation, setting up webgl is as bothersome as setting up opengl on desktop, link: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: @Rodrigo .. Just for the information.. how to embed it with html coding .. because at back end i'm seeing html type coding. means how we draw a line or dot on web form (c#) and do i have to code it at back end.?

Comment: There is no back end code (that I know of) to draw a line or anything using webgl on the client, everything has to happen on the client. That is javascript or canvas executing client side.

Comment: @Rodrigo .. without JavaScript I have to draw/render a dot or line on C# web Forms using WebGL/OpenGL ...